# Which is correct, "我对我的妈妈说很多话" or "我对我的妈妈说很多"?

Tags: grammar, mandarin

Can someone explain me which one is correct and why?

Comment: Both are correct, but "说**了**很多(话)" is better considering the tense.

Comment: it seems 对 can be replaced by 跟, see examples for "跟说" at jukuu (would 对 emphasize mother has to listen to speech by author? again see jukuu for examples for 对说)

Comment: @user6065 对 (to) implies telling and 跟 (and) implies two-way conversation.

Comment: Could there be users who do not know? It just seemed that the latter situation is the more common one for children talking to their mother.

Comment: Both are unnatural, just one of those things to do with good style

Comment: both the same meaning.

Comment: Putting aside the stylistic element and syntax which have already received some comments, the two sentences, IMO, actually have different meanings. The first is to say -- I have had a long conversation with my mother. The second, (which ought to be -- "...说了很多"), is to say -- I told my mother quite a lot already.

Answer (score 3):

First, in Chinese if you don't want to emphasize "我的，你的，他的"，we usually remove "我的”，我对我妈说....or 我对妈妈说 is more natural.

Secondly, it should be added a complement "了" after the verb "说" to indicate the action is finished. So it could be 我对妈妈说了很多话。or 我对妈妈说了很多。

Finally, 说了很多话 means that you speak a lot "sentence" to your mother, while 说了很多 means you talk a lot topics or opions with your mother.

Answer (score 2):

The first one seems to be more logic to the last one. But both of them are strange. I didn't get the point that what would you like to say.

To explain at least, the last sentence lacks object of verb "speak".

If they are declarative sentence, it's better to say 我对我的妈妈说了很多话 or 我对我的妈妈说了很多. Both of these are reasonable, but don't mean the same. The 2nd one seems to pull other points more, but 1st one didn't have this meaning.
It's complicated, wish that I've make it clearer to you.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context.

說很多話 can mean that you habitually talk to your mother a lot.

說(了)很多 means you have said a lot of things (regarding a specific subject).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, we often say it like this:

> 我和妈妈经常聊天

or

> 我对妈妈讲了很多

We usually drop the term 我的 if it is implicit but clear and unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

in most cases they are the same. Chinese has omissions of objective, that is, many verb has the most frequently used objective, like 说(话) and 吃(饭), so if you just use 说/吃 without objective, the objective could be regarded as 话/饭 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Which one is correct depends on the meaning you want to emphasize. To me, if the sentence is too long, I separate it into sub sentences. And if you still want to use the word `my` in the sentence. Thus, I would say:

`很多的话 我对我的妈妈说了`

But this can have another meaning than you wanted to emphasize. You can edit your question with your meaning what you wanted to say.